# Swipe, refresh, layout can be replace with lambda error

Tags: javascript, java, android, firebase, lambda

[image]

Showing this error when adding new Swipe Refresh Layout

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!. Please provide a [mcve] so we can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not an error. I see that you are using IntelliJ/Android Studio, this is the color code :

- Grey : suggestion
- Green : typo error
- Yellow : warning (you may have written something that could crash or you don't follow the rules)
- Red : An error

Also, try out what the IDE propose. You can do Alt-Enter to show suggestion ! It can refactor your code, in this case it would do it for you.

There is also the very important ctrl-space to show auto-complete. Another for the road : ctrl-atl-L will reformat the whole text with correct tab and column usage.

In your specific case it's because you can replace the `new ....` with a lambda

```
swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(() -> {
   // you code
});
```